# Choosing the right database: MySQL vs. Everything else

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, postgresql, database

It would seem these days that everyone just goes with MySQL because that's just what everyone goes with. I'm working on a web application that will be handling a large quantity of incoming data and am wondering if I should "just go with MySQL" or if I should take a look at other open-source databases or even commercial databases?

EDIT: Should have mentioned, am looking for optimal performance, integration with ruby + rails running on debian 5 and money is tight although if it will save money in the long run I would consider making an investment into something more expensive.

Comment: How optimal do you want? If you want the best performance money can buy, then that's different from having the best failover money can buy. And if money is tight, then you should probably mention that. Also, what's your development platform; it's not unreasonable to pick a solution which integrates well with your tooling and available data access layers.

Comment: 1) how much is "a large quantity of incoming data"?  2) is the data many tiny items inserted frequently, or few large items inserted infrequently?  3) does the data possess uniform structure (does all data posses the same fields)?  4) how do you plan to address scalability, vertically (faster proc, more RAM) or horizontally (distributed DB, sharding)? 5) how much time do you have to learn new things? 6) There are many other questions I could ask, but my point is to help you see that your question needs refinement.

Comment: 1) Dependent on amount of users however one user will be contributing a lot of data. 2) The data will be many tiny items inserted frequently. 3) Yes the data possess uniform structure. 4) I don't know, I've never had to "address scalability" before, however I have a feeling with this project I might have to, probably 'vertically'. 5) lots of time :-), within reason of course.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've posted this before, but I have no reason to change this advice:

MySQL is easier to start using.

Nicer UI tools. Faster, if you don't use ACID. More tolerant of invalid data. Autoincrement columns are as easy as typing autoincrement. Permissions aren't as tied to the file systems and OS users. Setting a delimiter is easier than using PG's "dollar sign quoting" when writing a stored proc. In MySQL, you connect to all databases, not just one at a time.

Postgres (PG) is much more standards compliant, but it's uglier and more complicated, especially from a UI perspective. It used to require manual vacuuming, and actually enforces referential integrity (which is a great thing that can be a pain in the ass). Autoincrement is much more flexible, but requires sequences (which can me masked by using serial), and wait, what's an OID?

So if you don't really know or care much about databases, data validity, ACID compliance, etc, but you do care about ease and speed, you tend to go with MySQL.

Too many (not all, but many) "web programmers" know a lot about "web 2.0" or PHP or Java, but don't know much about database theory or practice ("an index? what's that?"). They tend to see a database as just a fancy hashtable or bag of data, and indeed one that's not anywhere as dynamically changeable or forgiving as a hashtable.

For these folks, MySQL -- because until 5.0 it wasn't really an RDBMS, and in many ways still is not -- is a godsend. It's "faster" than the competition, and doesn't "waste time" on "esoteric" database stuff a web programmer doesn't want, understand, or see the value of.

For somebody with a database background, on the other hand, MySQL is a minefield: stuff that should work (complicated views, group bys, order bys in group bys) may work or may if you're lucky crash the server, or if you're unlucky just give results with incorrect data.

I've spent days working around some of these things in admittedly complicated by not extraordinarily complex views and group bys.

And MySQL isn't really faster. If you're using InnoDb tables for ACID (or just because at more than 30 Million rows, MyISAM tables tend to get crappy), yes a straight one-table select is probably faster than in PG. But add in joins, and PG is suddenly significantly faster. (MySQL is especially bad at outer joins.)

In summary: if to you the database is a bag, if you never intend to do data mining or reporting, if you're mostly interested in serving up big hunks of text with few relations or updates -- that is, if you're using a database to power a blog, MySQL is a great choice.

But if you're actually managing data, if you understand that data lives longer and is more valuable to a business than front-end programs and middle-tier business rules , if you need the features of a real database, use PG.

A "web programmer" who has decided all his table structures can be auto-generated by Hibernate (or some other ORM) looks at that and says, "too complicated" and "I bet complicated means more cost and slower speed" and so he goes with MySQL.

As I said, PG is far superior, and I hate mucking with MySQL's bizarre bugs, and I think that overall PG performance is probably better than MySQL for any even slightly complicated query.

But MySQL makes things look (deceptively) simple, so you get a lot of people who don't really understand database design figuring that MySQL is a great choice.

Use PG. It's consistent, it's reliable, it's standards-compliant, it's faster on (even moderately) complicated queries, it doesn't completely throw off your schedule with weird bugs.

Comment: This is a great answer, I have used PostgreSQL since 8.x and haven't had to mess with OIDs or even deal with setting up sequences (I know they are there).  This may be due to the fact that anything that I have done has been small scale.  I think pg is great and I would use it over MySQL *any* day of the week, mainly because of all the gotchas and weird bugs you get with MySQL.

Answer (score 21):

I think [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) is a very viable alternative to MySQL.  It's much more Oracle-like.

Comment: For open source databases, PostgreSQL has my "money" every time. See my own answer as to why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831849/choosing-the-right-database-mysql-vs-everything-else/831986#831986

Comment: Rather, MySQL is a somewhat viable alternative to PostgreSQL.

Comment: An explanation of "somewhat viable" would be nice.

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I try to avoid MySQL whenever I can for the following reasons:

1. The **default** storage engine MyISAM lacks [Foreign Key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) support. [Innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb.html) does, however it does not support Foreign Keys to MyISAM tables for obvious reasons.
2. If I attempt to insert invalid data, MySQL will happily change it for me.

   1. Illegal DateTime, Date, or Timestamp values are convert to "zero": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html
   2. Varchar and Char type columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html
   3. Numeric Datatypes depending on SQL Strict Mode: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

These things may not be of any importance to some people, but when it comes to quality of data, I would rather use something else.

Comment: So, what do you use and why? :-)

Comment: It depends on the project. For open source databases, I prefer PostgreSQL because it has out of the box support for Foreign Keys, and if I attempt to insert invalid data, it throws errors at me.

Comment: Yep, I agree, MySQL is great (easy, small, fast enough for small and medium projects but can handle huge amounts of data at the same time) but its down side is that it feels like DB with PHP mindset. And not even think in migrating vast amounts of data from servers with slightly different versions... you'll end up hanging yourself with the mouse cable.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are may differences between the RDBMS of the world.
Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Fundamental_features

Using this as a guide you should be able to narrow down your choices a lot.

A few things to keep in mind:

SQL Server 2005 Express is limited to a 4GB file size, but has excellent support int the  .NET and Java languages.

MySQL will run on both Windows and Linux, and many languages support it (including .NET and Java) with external libraries.

SQLite is supported by effectively every operating system, and can be distributed as an integrated part of your application.

Comment: SQLite does not have Foreign Keys

Comment: Correct, that is, in fact, mentioned by the link i posted.

Answer (score 4):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) the open sourced and branched version of Borland's Interbase is pretty good, it works happily on most (all?) flavours of Linux and is very performant. I am not a RoR guy so I don't know the details, but I do have a friend in NZ who uses Firebird with all his RoR projects, it definitely works with RoR, and works well.

**Edit:** 
Found a link to a Firebird Rails Adapter [here](http://fireruby.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Please be a little wary of the idealistic points-of-view put forth by people who may have axes to grind. MySQL is a capable, robust and scalable solution for many problems, but this is usually not so right out-of-the-box as its defaults are extremely conservative. Like any database product, you will need to spend time tuning its installation for the desired performance. You will also need to spend some time accomodating its limitations, which is also true for any database you choose.

MySQL's popularity is partly self-generated: a lot of hosting providers provide it, so a lot of people use it.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql is great, and mssql is great. I haven't used anything else. I would say if you are completely on the fence, go with the technology stack you are strongest with. I have a good amount of c#, asp.net, and other Microsoft stack experience, so it is pretty natural for me to specialize in mssql. If you are more familiar with *nix, php, etc, you may be more at home sticking to an open source stack. You can certainly mix and match the two stacks, but sticking to one world or the other can avoid some pain for you.

Comment: I don't really mind a down vote on an answer if my answer stinks, but I would love to hear the opposing view.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your answer. And the down voter doesn't seem to give an explanation too. So, have put you back to zero.

Comment: Postgresql has great .NET bindings for example by the company Devart. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

Answer (score 2):

Like duffymo I also recommend PostgreSQL. It is very nice from a developer perspective: 
work on many platforms (both unix-based and Windows), has vary stable interfaces to any laguage/environment I worked (Windows, Linux, Delphi, Java, Perl, Python). Stored procedure language: PLPGSQL is also easy and powerful. User support (newsgroups, lists, SO) is nice and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

"It would seem these days that everyone just goes with MySQL because that's just what everyone goes with." If MySQL is the only thing that people use then why are Oracle and MSSQL still around?

The debate as to which database engine to go for can be talked about until the cows come home. I personally have always found one constant in choosing a databse engine. The one you can afford is generally the one you go for.

If you can justify spending XXX on a database then you probably know the reasons already for choosing it.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I meant in the web development "web 2.0" scene.

Comment: I totally stopped using MySQL when Oracle Express was released, but that's because Oracle is the best option for the type of apps I usually work with but my pockets are not that deep.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is easy to install and it works fine without special settings. With the proper approach MySQL can flexibly adjust to your needs. But there are also some pitfalls: in some cases it may slow down your project, no matter how well you have tuned the DBMS and the data structure.

MySQL is for you if:

- you do not want to delve into DBMS settings;
- you think structurally;
- integration with MySQL is in any programming language, framework,    CMS, CMF and so on;
- you need DBMS to manage small structural data (up to 1 or 2 gigabytes).

You mentioned, that you deal with large quantity of incoming data. Probably this [guide](https://softmedialab.com/blog/database-choice-for-large-data-volume/) would be helpful